# Low CPU usage when performing big task in java

Tags: mac, java, cpu

I recently got mac mini and I'm new to OS X so maybe this is a trivial question.
I'm developing web application in java using Spring. I have another project to run IT tests which sets up the API and performs lots of testing.

Tests take ~6 minutes on Linux and Windows (and when this is first thing i do after restarting my mac).
When i run them on my mac they take very long time (~30 mins and go on)
I notice in Activity Monitor that CPU is 90% idle after the API has started and tests begin to execute. Java processes uses ~0.5% of CPU. There is still ~7 GB memory free.

Running this on other environments (e.g. Linux) usually takes most of available resources (almost 100% CPU usage and memory)

Can somebody help me resolve this issue? Does OS X have any limitation regarding CPU usage for java processes?

I can provide more informations but need to know where to look.

Comment: Is your "IT test [suite]" available in the public?

Comment: are you asking about project sources? It is not available in public.

Comment: Are you running it via command line or an IDE? (Some IDEs negatively affect performance). Also, is the program throwing any uncaught errors?

Comment: No errors- test do execute but very slowly. Running it via command line using maven

Comment: I'm using Check Point endpont security to connect to VPN. Disconnecting seems to resolve this issue which makes me even more confused

Comment: What are the specs of your Mac? What is the CPU/year? (If it is an equivalent machine compared to Linux and Windows it should take around same time too... It is strange that it takes 30 min)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this looks like an issue with the VPN and the specific app that we have no details of. There is no way for anyone but the OP to debug this and they have not provided the required extra information for several years

Answer (score 1):

Is the console output slowing the application? Does the app use System.out or a logging framework like log4j?

I just [solved a similar issue for a Java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64470541/java-app-is-using-1-cpu-after-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-to-20-04?noredirect=1#comment113999848_64470541) and the behavior occurred after an update - the MySQL slow query log showed that the insert was taking 1 second but in reality a batch insert was being split into 1000 some inserts after the default behavior in the JDBC driver changed from auto commit being off for batch commits to having it on (which required me to manually turn off auto commits for batch inserts).